# How do I install drivers for a NVIDIA 720M on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Today I installed Ubuntu for the very first time. I am having trouble installing any drivers for my GT 720M card.

I've tried to follow the guides for general NVIDIA driver installation but haven't had any success. Likewise, the "additional drivers" program fails to detect anything.

I would really appreciate any instructions to be typed out in baby-steps. Traditionally, I'm a Windows user, and I'm unfamiliar with what are, probably, basic operations.

Comment: Are you running 64bit or 32bit?  you can see that by running `uname -a` on terminal.

Comment: Most possibly your card is a hybrid card. See -[How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](http://askubuntu.com/q/36930)

Comment: I'm running 64bit

Comment: Is there any problem right now with the drivers you have installed?

Comment: 'Under system setting - details - Graphics' there is no information

Answer (score 0):

Add this ppa repository: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates

To do that, open the Terminal and type (in this order):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates 
sudo apt-get update
```

When you type the first command, you will be asked to type your password. (Note that while you are typing your password you won't see anything on the screen. Don't worry: that's normal.)

Then try to open "additional drivers" again and check if it finds any driver.

PS: to learn what Repositories and PPAs are, take a look here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

PPS: Welcome to Ubuntu and GNU/Linux ;)

Comment: I did some research and I think that the driver version in that repository is too old for your GPU. Try that anyway. If it doesn't work I'll suggest you another PPA.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I followed the two commands but the additional driver list is still empty.

Comment: Ok, then first remove the previous ppa using this command:

`sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`

Then try with this ppa: https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa

So, like before:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` and 
`sudo apt-get update`

and then check "additional drivers" again.

Comment: While trying to remove the previous ppa, I got an error message saying "...doesn't exist in sourcelist file".

Comment: This is strange... Are you sure you actually added the x-swat ppa? Did you notice that when you add a ppa, after a while it asks you to confirm by pressing ENTER? If you open "Software & Updates" and click to "Other Software", do you see that ppa in the list?

Comment: `Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~ubuntu-x-swat/ubuntu/x-updates'.
The team named '~ubuntu-x-swat' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/x-updates'`